# ListView and items with countdown timer

Tags: android, listview, countdowntimer, multiplication

i have a issue with my Listview, i want to set a countdown timer to all ListView's items, and i allready have googled a solution for this, but it isn't work correctly. The Problem is that ListView reuses(recycling) a views, and i always get a wrong item time. I use a tag for my view, but it still not work, i can't understand where i made a mistake, please help me. thx.

So here a pictures that shows my problem:
pic1 Where i've just started an Activity;
[image: startActivity]

pic2 Where i've just scrolled down and up

[image: listWithError]

And here my code(whole class):

## UPDATED

```
    public class PromoListActivity extends SherlockActivity {
private ListView mPromoList;
private PromoListAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewFlipper mFlipper;
private Button mBtnRepeat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_news_list);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setTitle("Сохранённые акции");
    mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    mPromoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsList);
    mBtnRepeat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    
    //-->
    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // run every minute
        }
    };
    //<--
    
    
    mBtnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
            getDummyData();
        }
    });
    mPromoList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PromoListActivity.this, PromoActivityDetails.class));

        }
    });
    getDummyData();
}

private class PromoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<PromoAction> mItems = new ArrayList<PromoAction>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private PromoListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PromoAction> mItems) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mItems = mItems;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public PromoAction getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewItem viewItem;
        PromoAction promoAction = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewItem = new ViewItem();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitem_action, null);
            viewItem.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.promoAction_name);
            viewItem.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.promoAction_desc);
            viewItem.timer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.promoAction_timer);
            viewItem.timer.setTag(position);
            convertView.setTag(viewItem);
        } else {
            viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        setTime(promoAction,viewItem.timer,viewItem.timer.getTag().toString());
        viewItem.name.setText(promoAction.name);
        viewItem.desc.setText(promoAction.descr);
        return convertView;
    }

    private void setTime(final PromoAction promoAction, final TextView tv, final String tag) {
        if (tv.getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
            long outputTime = Math.abs(promoAction.timer_end
                    - System.currentTimeMillis());
            Date date = new java.util.Date(outputTime);
            String result = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(date);
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }

    public class ViewItem {
        TextView name;
        TextView desc;
        TextView timer;
    }
}

private void getDummyData() {
    ArrayList<PromoAction> list = new ArrayList<PromoAction>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        PromoAction action = new PromoAction();
        action.name = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
        action.descr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ";
        switch (i) {
        case 1: {
            action.timer_start = 1385971000;
            action.timer_end = 1386104000;
        }
        case 2: {
            action.timer_start = 1385889000;
            action.timer_end = 1385812550;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            action.timer_start = 1385884200;
            action.timer_end = 1385912100;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            action.timer_start = 1385856000;
            action.timer_end = 1385892000;
            break;
        }
        }
        list.add(action);

    }
    mAdapter = new PromoListAdapter(PromoListActivity.this, list);
    mPromoList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this differently in my case. Instead of having a timer handler set inside your `getView()`, I just set the time difference between the current time and your desired time to the `TextView` every time `getView()` is called. So move this code of yours back inside `getView()`:

```
long outputTime = Math.abs(promoAction.timer_end
                    - System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = new java.util.Date(outputTime);
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(date);
tv.setText(result);
```

Then create a handler in the activity to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` every one minute on the listview's adapter:

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 60000); //run every minute
    }
};
```

I stop this handler on `onPause()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    super.onPause();
}
```

And I start it again on `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 500);
    super.onResume();
}
```

And that's it. :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't have a timer itself, as you see my code, i use handler to call notifyDataSetChanged() just like you, i didn't get why listview set wrong timers to its child, whatever it was thanks for your answer

Comment: @whizzzkey You are having the timer handler inside the `getView()`. Don't do that. Try to do it like I suggested to see if it works.

Comment: hmm...your solution is not working at all, items update their time only when they get out of screen, and it still view caching and shows me wrong time. I did all as you wrote.

Comment: Can you post the new code of your class? You can't cache the code for updating the time, by the way. You need to let `getView()` compute it every time.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you have the `if (tv.getTag().toString().equals(tag))` inside your `setTime()` call? I think you can remove it.

Comment: Yeah, it is just a copypast =) not important

Comment: Also, you need to start the handler outside of it as well. In your `onCreate()`, just add `timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 500);` after you declare the handler and the runnable.

Comment: I think best solution is to use scrollview with dynamically inflating layouts INSTEAD listview, just had seen your answer, i trying to do it now

Comment: If you don't have too many items, maybe dynamically inflating layouts will work better. But the solution I gave you above works. I have it working on an app of mine. Hope you can find a solution for your case.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!! THANKS A LOT!! that is what i searching for, and works without problems, THX!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recyclerview. Download source code from here ()

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scrollbars="vertical" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.androidsolutionworld.multipletimer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList al_data = new ArrayList<>();
    private Adapter obj_adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        al_data.add("1234");
        al_data.add("1257");
        al_data.add("100");
        al_data.add("1547");
        al_data.add("200");
        al_data.add("500");
        al_data.add("2000");
        al_data.add("1000");

        obj_adapter = new Adapter(al_data);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
    }
}
```

**adapter_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_timer"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom Adapter:**

```
package com.androidsolutionworld.multipletimer;


import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private ArrayList al_data;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView tv_timer;
        CountDownTimer timer;

        public MyViewHolder (View view){
            super(view);
            tv_timer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);

        }


    }

    public Adapter(ArrayList al_data) {
        this.al_data = al_data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout,parent,false);


        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_timer.setText(al_data.get(position));

        if (holder.timer != null) {
            holder.timer.cancel();
        }
         long timer = Long.parseLong(al_data.get(position));

        timer = timer*1000;

        holder.timer = new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              holder.tv_timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000 + " Sec");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                holder.tv_timer.setText("00:00:00");
            }
        }.start();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return al_data.size();
    }



}
```

Thanks!